# Editor access to menu: custom post type missing

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, editor

I have used this code;

```
$roleObject = get_role( 'editor' );
if (!$roleObject->has_cap( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) {
    $roleObject->add_cap( 'edit_theme_options' );
}
```

to add menu access for editors.

I have a custom post type 'Masterclasses". That appears correctly in the Administrator's Menu editing page but doesn't appear in the Editor's Menu editing page.

How do I add this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As ever, when you know the answer it's maddeningly simple. The custom post types were there all along, together with their taxonomy. All posts are absent from the menu editor and have to be turned on in Screen Options.

I pressed the button and lo, there they were.

Comment: Thanks, this is non-obvious as hell UX. The CPT boxes do not seem like meta boxes, which you would expect Screen Options to control.

Comment: Agree with @lkraav. If items are hidden, a link below the selection indicating how they can be added would be better UX.

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving capabilities for something like `add_cap( 'edit_Masterclasses' )`

For more you can refer to this documentation
http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Editor

Comment: Half the problem (when searching for this online) is the confusion between this capability - to edit the custom post type - they already can. What I need is to add the Masterclasses to the Appearance-menu possibilities. Admin can Editor can't